# Non-static parameter inside a static function

Tags: c++, class, variables, static, non-static

I have this static callback function in MyClass, and I try to call another static function from it. There is a problem however, one of the arguments that Register() takes is a non-static class variable.

I thought of using the "this" keyword to overcome this problem but it seems I am unable to  ('this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions). Here is my code:

```
class MyClass
{
...
    static LRESULT CALLBACK klHkProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    static BOOL Register(DWORD vKey,KEYBLOCK* ptrKEYBLOCK);
    KEYBLOCK *kb;       
...

}
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::klHkProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) (lParam);
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) 
    {
        MyClass::Register(p->vkCode,this->kb);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Static functions can't access instance members. Where do you want to get the instance from?

Comment: Do you have a place to pass extra data into wherever you register your callback?  If so, you can pass `this` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you wrote it is hard to answer this without more information.

However, assuming that all instances of `MyClass` should be processed, I suggest adding a `static std::list<MyClass *>` into which you place each instance's `this` pointer in the constructor for `MyClass` and then in the destructor of `MyClass` to remove the `this` from this list.

Then in your static klHkProc() you would iterate over the static list of all instances of `MyClass` and for each one call `MyClass::Register()` with the `kb` of each such registered instance of `MyClass`.

Here is a rough outline of the code to do this:

```
class MyClass
{
...
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK klHkProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    static BOOL Register(DWORD vKey,KEYBLOCK* ptrKEYBLOCK);
    static std::list<MyClass *> allInstances;
    KEYBLOCK *kb;

    MyClass() {
      ...
      allInstances.push_back(this);
      ...
    }
    ~MyClass() {
      ...
      // Assumes not a huge list of instances as this is O(n) and thus destruction
      // of all instances of MyClass in O(n^2) on the number of instances.
      allInstances.remove(this);
      ...
    }

...
};

LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::klHkProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) (lParam);
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        std::list<MyClass *> itr = allInstances.begin();
        std::list<MyClass *> end = allInstances.end();
        for (; itr != end; ++itr) {
          MyClass *current = *itr;
          MyClass::Register(p->vkCode, current->kb);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Each instance of the class would have a pointer to the current KeyBlock object, this needs to be different for every instance, as each instance uses different keyblocks. I want to use the Register function to record a keypress into the KeyBlock object of the specific instance

Comment: So this is a keypress event from the user and upon each keypress event you wish to take the registered action?

Comment: How do you know which instance of `MyClass` should be the target of the keypress event? Also, on the keypress is `klHkProc()` being called or is something being done with the registered item?

Comment: I have each class create it's own thread and capturing keystrokes at the same time, so basically all instances. klHkProc is set via SetWindowsHookEx

Comment: Do I understand correctly that all threads in your application are supposed to process each keystroke event.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit connection between a static member and any particular object instance.

You could pass a pointer or reference to a `MyClass` object to `klHkProc()`, which it can then pass to `Register()`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, If KEYBLOCK *kb is not static you cannot reference it inside the static function. the 'this' pointer only makes sense inside an instance of an object. So, if KEYBLOCK *kb only makes sense inside an instantiated object then,  you would have to instantiate a MyClass inside Register or klHkProc. It would be easier to determine whether the latter makes sense to instantiate MyClass inside Register or not if you gave us a better context of what Register is supposed to be doing rather than just the showing the caller.